# C++: overloading subscript operator (different return typ)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

I know that a return value is not enough to override a function (and I read different threads about it on stackoverflow), but is there a way to overload the subscript operator of a class, just to return the value (I can't changed to to return by reference-type of function)

It has to look like or at least work like:

What's the best approach to solve this problem (It has to be a operator)?

Update:
The Problem is, that's not allowed to just overload a member or operator just with the return type.

```
struct A {int a; int b; double c;};
struct B {int a; int b; array<double,2> c;};

class Whatever
{
public:
A operator [](unsigned int ) const; //it's just reading the element
B operator [](unsigned int ) const;
}

A operator [](unsigned int Input){
//...
}

B operator [](unsigned int Input){
//...
}
```

Comment: You could create a nested class in `Whatever` that deals with only one type, and use a getter function to return this type that wraps a `Whatever` and provides the operator.

Comment: You could also have one operator that returns a proxy class that implements conversion operators. But at some point your code will become too confusing.

Comment: You failed to identify the *problem*..

Comment: This isn't a direct solution to your problem, so I am not going to post it as an answer, but I'd suggest just using two separate functions, rather than attempt to use one operator twice. `A getA( unsigned int ) const;` and `B getB( unsigned int ) const;`. It might not seem as clear/simple now, but it will be more so than trying to use tricks to get [] to do what you want done.

Comment: So how do you expect this to work: `std:: cout << Whatever()[0].a;` ? You should be able to specify class at some point explicitly

Comment: No, I mean what's the *real* problem? Why does it have to an operator?

Comment: @William Kappler: Unfortunately, I can't just change the name of the operator but thanks for your reply

Comment: So you have some template code which assumes the existence of `operator[]` but must work for both `A` and `B`? If it's a template, won't it work anyway for both types? I think you should post some more code so that we understand the context of the situation.

Comment: It starts to look like a typical XY problem...

Comment: The Real aim is to use an already existing routine (unchanged) for two different input vectors. That means at the end I have to be able to use the same formula (like (vect[a].b * xx[vect[a].b];)) for both notations. It not a big deal to adopt the subscript operator for each notation but I can't combine them

Comment: If you need this done for some external reason, then I suggest a wrapper class which returns either A or B when [] is called. Then, implement the real, internal interface as I outlined. I am not aware of a way to make any function return separate types with otherwise the exact same declaration.

Comment: @WilliamKappler You can simulate this with a proxy object with conversion operators. But it would be easily confused when the target can accept multiple types, such as `std::cout`

Comment: I don't have a template, I thought a template might be a solution (I read some threads on stackexchange and it seemed to be a way to make it work but I'm new to c++ and I don't know what might be the best approach to solve the problem)

Comment: At the end of the day, an overloaded operator is just another function. There is no really fundamental difference, so the overloading rules are identical.

Comment: You want to template `operator[]` by return type? It may be possible, but I'm not sure the syntax, in any case it will be ugly. You might as well just use a templated getter function.

Comment: So do you need both operator versions on the _same instance_ of the object or you know what type of object operator should return at compile time? In the latter case you can make `Whatever` template and parametrise it over operator return type

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know what kind of type you are going to access, you can return a proxy which converts to either type and, probably, does the access upon conversion. Since you want to access a `const` object that should be fairly straight forward. Things get a bit more messy when trying to do the same for an updating interface:

```
class Whatever;
class Proxy {
    Whatever const* object;
    int             index;
public:
    Proxy(Whatever const* object, int index)
        : object(object)
        , index(index) {
    }
    operator A() const { return this->object->asA(this->index); }
    operator B() const { return this->object->asB(this->index); }
};
class Whatever {
    // ...
public:
    Proxy operator[](int index) { return Proxy(this, index); }
    A asA(index) { ... }
    B asB(index) { ... }
};
```

The main constraint is that you can't access members of `A` and `B` directly: you need to convert to an `A` or a `B` first. If the two types are actually known, you can created a `Proxy` which forwards the respective member function appropriately. Of course, if there are commonly named member functions or data members you'll need to explicitly convert first.